# Research on machine vision and game solvers

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, game-development

I am currently creating an intelligent agent for a game solver. This system will be hosted in a computer different from the host of the game which it will play. Hence, I am looking for similar researches or projects that uses machine vision for a game solver. The game is a board game/involving tiles, by the way.

These are the things I think I need to do:

- Edge detection
- Pattern recognition
- Board/tile detection similar to that is being used to detecting chess boards

I really cannot find something that can be beneficial to me using Google search, even using advance searching in Google scholar does not give me relevant research.

Comment: Why can't you just send the board information to the agent? You're just going to have to rebuild the board as a datatype anyway, so why not simplify things and just send that information from the server hosting the game?

Also, please post images of the game board, it will help a lot regarding what types of vision methods you should use.

Comment: I would if I am allowed to that. This is actually a research topic (not an assignment, more like a final paper or semi-thesis, so I must cite some resources) that was given to me. One of the questions I must answer is: How would an intelligent agent fare if they are to use machine vision instead of just sitting on the host computer of the game? I'm still new in this field, so I want to read other researches regarding this.The game can be checkers or minesweeper, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a multi-step process, no single algorithm is going to do it all for you, and few researchers ever give out their full algorithms they used to solve problems. But all the pieces you'll want to use to do your own work are well documented.

Basically, you'll want to use edge detection and maybe also region growing to find the board, and then something like Hough circle detection to find the game pieces (assuming it's checkers, if it's minesweeper, you open up a whole other can of worms with OCR).

You won't need anything related to patter recognition or machine learning for the vision part. You'll be giving it a very clean image of a board with very strict rules about how it will look and act. So just write your code for that board and that problem.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a full algorithm. Actually, my professor wants the intelligent agent to play minesweeper. I'm thinking of using an ANN as a digit classifier. OCR is really difficult. One thing I am still thinking of is how I will I make the video frames look good so that it will be easier to process or maybe I'd just buy a more powerful video cam for that. Thanks by the way. I'd mark yours as an answer for helping me :D

Comment: Since you are working with a very strict set of characters (as opposed to handwritten), ANN should work reasonably well. Don't forget to consider both shape and color, as minesweeper uses both.

Also, you might want to do a screen capture stream rather than using a camcorder. That would solve problems like glare, dim images, and skew angles. This will be especially important for minesweeper where the tile edges are (from a CV perspective) not all that well defined.

Unless your professor really wants it to be done with a real camera.

Comment: my professor wants it to be done with a real camera because it's not really a solver, my bad, but a player. by extension, it must use at least one human sense, which in this case sense of sight. it should be an autonomous intelligent agent game player. thanks for your advice. it seems that there is really no related lit that I can cite :(